# Javassist: To replace a statement in a function

Tags: java, javassist

Using javassist, I was able to change the entire method content by using `setBody()`.

Is there a way to just `replace` just a statement in the method instead.

Please find the code below:

```
ctClass.instrument(new ExprEditor() {
        @Override
        public void edit(FieldAccess fieldAccess)
                throws CannotCompileException {
            //System.out.println(fieldAccess.getFieldName());
        if (fieldAccess.getFieldName().equals("out")) {             

            fieldAccess.replace(" { System.out.println(\"Manipulating.. \"); $_ = $proceed($$); } ");                
            }
        }           
    }
```

My intent is to "replace" a `System.out.println(" ");` in the main java program dynamically.

When I try to do this(above method), I see that this approach just adds a line to the beginning of the method, just before the `System.out.println` it was supposed to replace. The previous `System.out.println`statement still exists in my code.

Am I doing something wrong here? It would be great if I could get some pointers.

Comment: Reference Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930400/adding-a-statement-using-javassist?rq=1